# If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, then $n$ is the minimal such that $g^n=1$ for all $g \in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I know that if the order of a finite group $G$ is $n$ then $g^n=1$ for all $g\in G$. But, is $n$ the smaller integer that satisfies that property? There isn't another $m<n$ such that $g^m=1$ for all $g\in G$?
Thanks

Comment: No. The group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ has order 4, but $x^2=1$ for all $x\in G$.

Comment: You can also think of Cauchy's theorem - If $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime divisor of $|G|$ then $G$ has an element of order $p$.

Comment: The least number $n$ of a finite group $G$ such that $x^n=1$ for all $x\in G$ is called the _exponent_ of the group, and you usually have $exp(G)<|G|$.

Comment: @Rise You are making the same mistake I did.  The OP isn't saying that no element has order less than n.  The OP is saying no number less than n works for all elements.  In which case, any noncyclic group will have no element requiring n so some number less than n is sufficient.

Comment: @fleablood. Thank you. I got it! But I shall leave the comment intact so that people reading this post in the future don't make the same mistake as we did.

Comment: @egreg Not true - $S_3$ or the nonabelian group of order $21$ are counterexamples. The condition implies only that all the Sylow Subgroups are cyclic.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, you're right; it is if $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 3):

A finite group of order $n$ will have exponent $n$ if and only if its Sylow Subgroups are cyclic for every $p|n$.

Suppose $p^r$ is the highest power of $p$ which divides $n$ (and $r\ge 1)$. If the Sylow subgroups associated with $p$ are not cyclic, then there is no element with order $p^r$, and hence no element with order divisible by $p^r$ and the exponent is at most $\frac np$.

On the other hand if there are elements $a_p$ of order $p^r$ for all $p$ the exponent of the group cannot be lower than the least common multiple of their orders, which is $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Third attempt.  In general no.  $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ is the simplest exception.  Many such examples will exist.  I tried to generalize but I made mistakes.  I think if $n = pq$ for prime p and q. Then this will be true as some element g will have order p and only $g^{kp} = 1$ while another h will have order q and only $h^{jq} = 1$ so the only $m$ so that $h^m = e = g^m$ is $n = pq = lcm(p,q)$.

I think for any other $n = p^im; i > 0$ it will be possible to find groups of order n where $g^{pm} = e$ for all elements and thus this wouldn't be true.  (Ex. $\prod_i \mathbb Z_p \times G'$ where G' is a subgroup of order m.)

(Of course you will also be able to find groups where $n$ *is* the smallest such number.  [Ex. $\mathbb Z_n$])

I sure hope after being wrong twice that this one is correct....

=====

So I think in general, if $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ for primes $p_i$.  There will be groups where the lowest such number (called the exponent) is $\prod p_i^{j_i}$ for every possible $0 \le j_i \le k_i$.

At least, I really hope so.  I've embarrassed myself enough tonight.

Comment: This is false. Consider the cyclic group of order $m$, with $m$ composite: its generator has order $m$.

Comment: Consider the non-abelian group of order $21$ - this has elements of order $3$ and $7$, so the exponent is $21$.

Comment: Oh.  I thought the OP was claiming that all non-identity elements had order n.  Not that n is the smallest to satisfy all elements.

Comment: @MarkBennet are you claiming that the non-abelian group of order 21 has an element has order 21?

Comment: @MarkBennet  I'm confused.  If a group of order 21 has an element, g, of order 21 then every element of the group equals $g^i$ and $g^ig^j = g^{i+j}= g^jg^i$ by associativity so such a group is abelian.

Comment: I'm not saying that it has an element of order $21$, but that if $a$ has order $3$ and $b$ has order $7$ then the least $n$ for which it is true that $a^n=b^n=1$ is $n=21$

Comment: Ah, I see.  Good point.

Comment: @fleablood Just one more small correction in your last statement: $j_i = 0$ does not occur because of Cauchy's theorem (there is always an element of order $p_i$). Otherwise I think that statement is correct.