# $G$ is a finite group, if $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $g^m=1$ for all $g\in G$, then $m=n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove / disprove: Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$, if $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $g^m=1$ for all $g\in G$, then $m=n$.

I can't find a group that will satisfy this condition so I think it's wrong, it's also kind of similar to the little theorem but it would have to be $m = n-1$. What is the counter example to disprove this?

Also, would it be right if implication was $m= n-1$ because of the little theorem?

Comment: Have you tried some small examples? Like for example both the groups of order $4$?

Comment: And your reference to the little theorem (I assume Fermat's) seems to indicate that you have rather misunderstood what that theorem says in relation to group theory.

Comment: ...look at a group of order 8...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy It is called order $8$, and if one does not pick it correctly, that will not help (also, one can do with a smaller order).

Comment: A slip of the mind but thank you. The group we are referring to is the one that first came to mind for me.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't see how it satisfies the condition, since $2^x mod 4 = 0 \forall x$...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy I am not sure which group you are referring to, as there are a total of $5$ different groups of order $8$ and only one of them fails to provide an example here.

Comment: Keep it ["klein"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) (Dutch for small).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well I'm not thinking of that one!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can even take the trivial group to find a counterexample.

Comment: @pjs36 you mean $G=\{1\}$ then $1^9=1$ but $9\neq 1$ ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552795/if-g-is-a-finite-group-of-order-n-then-n-is-the-minimal-such-that-gn-1?rq=1

Comment: Can it be disproved with a group of this kind $\mathbb Z_x$ for some $x$ ?

Comment: @kuhaku Indeed I do :)

Comment: For all cyclic group (ie the groups which you call $\mathbb{Z}_x$) this property holds.

Comment: @JackYoon I think I'm doing it wrong because I don't see it, can you show an example please (with say x=4) ?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: @JackYoon $\mathbb Z_4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$ or $\mathbb Z^{\times}_4=\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Order of 1 and 3 is 4 so clearly the statement you write down holds. So it is not a counter example.

Comment: @JackYoon so the group has to be non cyclic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35348/discussion-between-jack-yoon-and-kuhaku).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest $m$ such that $g^m=1$ for all $g\in G$ is called the *exponent* of $G$.

The exponent of $G$ is a divisor of the order of $G$ and in general is a *proper* divisor.

For abelian groups, the exponent of $G$ equals the order of $G$ iff $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

Take $G=C_2 \times \cdots \times C_2$, with $n \gt 1$ factors. Then $g^2=1$ for all $g \in G$, but $|G|=2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to find special counterexample. If $g^n = 1$ for all $g\in G$, then $g^{2n}=g^ng^n=1\cdot 1 = 1$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: The question is whether $m$ must equal $n$. How can one justify your assertion that "In general $m$ is ... not equal to $n$" without a special counterexample?

Comment: $m$ also need not be a multiple of $n$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Let $m=2n$, then proof is over since $2n > n$ for all positive integer n.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you for correcting my post. But I can't think how it is possible...

Comment: As hinted at in the comments, consider the non-cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: This answer is correct for the question that was posted but I think the question should have said: if $m$ is the lowest common multiple of order of all $g\in G$ then is $m=n$?